# How to install bcmath in Ubuntu for PHP 7.1

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, php-7.1, bcmath

I'm using an Ubuntu 16 server for testing with `php7.1`. One of my app uses `bcadd` function. I know that I need to install `bcmath` module for that but I'm unable to find `php7.1-bcmath`. When I tried to install `apt install php-bcmath`, it simply installed `php7.0-bcmath` module.

I was unable to find `php7.1-bcmath` module anywhere to install on my server. Does anybody has an idea?

`apt install php7.1-bcmath` returned following,

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-bcmath

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-bcmath'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-bcmath'
```

Answer (score 62):

Answering my own question. Managed to fix this issue with following repo update.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Restart apache and all good to go.

Comment: How could you install `php7.1` originally if you don't have a ppa with it? o_O

Comment: Note that as of 2020, you should be installing the PHP 7.4 version, `apt install php7.4-bcmath`.

Answer (score 15):

install this : 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/artful/amd64/php7.1-bcmath/download

add this :

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main universe
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  -> 404  Not Found. Didn't worked for me

Comment: Thanks this works for me on 7.3 i used - sudo apt install php7.3-bcmath

Answer (score 13):

Those who are looking for Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

It will automatically install the bcmath compatible with your version of PHP.

In order to install the specific version of bcmath for php, you can use following command:

```
sudo apt install php7.x-bcmath
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04: Add this ppa http://ppa.launchpad.net/jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp/ubuntu
Open synaptic, and then uninstall any bcmath module already installed. Then reinstall php7.4 and php7.4-xxx modules