# Unable to install php7.1-bcmath on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-16.04, symfony4

When I run the following command : `composer require sonata-project/notification-bundle`  I have this error:

```
- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.0 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - sonata-project/notification-bundle 3.4.0 requires enqueue/amqp-lib ^0.8 -> satisfiable by enqueue/amqp-lib[0.8.0, 0.8.10, 0.8.11, 0.8.12, 0.8.13, 0.8.15, 0.8.2, 0.8.21, 0.8.23, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.9].
```

Apparently bcmath is missing so I have run this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath
```

And I get the error below:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-bcmath'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-bcmath'
```

Any idea what causing the problem ?

Symfony 4
php 7.1
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.1 bcmath Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905580/php-7-1-bcmath-not-working)

Comment: @KasperFranz, I have tried as explained in the link you gave me but it didn't work .  `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php7.1-bcmath`

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: @KasperFranz, This is the output: `E: Unable to locate package php7.1-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-bcmath'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-bcmath'`

Comment: what happened when you did the other commands linked out in the other issue?

Comment: Search for the package with apt-cache search bcmath and let me know what's the output

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```