# Install php7.1-bcmath on Debian

Tags: php, debian, php-7.1, bcmath

I'm trying to install **bcmath for PHP 7.1** on **Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)** :

`apt install php7.1-bcmath` throw a not found error.

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  dh-php libexporter-tiny-perl liblist-moreutils-perl libssl-doc pkg-php-tools shtool xml2
Veuillez utiliser « apt autoremove » pour les supprimer.
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  php7.1-bcmath
0 mis à jour, 1 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 266 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 15,8 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 65,5 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Err:1 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 php7.1-bcmath amd64 7.1.24-1+0~20181112093455.10+stretch~1.gbp09a4fd
  404  Not Found
E: Impossible de récupérer https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-bcmath_7.1.24-1+0~20181112093455.10+stretch~1.gbp09a4fd_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Impossible de récupérer certaines archives, peut-être devrez-vous lancer apt-get update ou essayer avec --fix-missing ?
```

I've already tried an `apt-get update --fix-missing` with no success.

It's seems specific to php7.1 because when I try other versions everything seems fine and ask for confirmation:

```
apt-get install php-bcmath
apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
```

Comment: Try this out sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-bcmath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install bcmath in Ubuntu for PHP 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905580/how-to-install-bcmath-in-ubuntu-for-php-7-1)

Comment: @MaartendeWolf already tried `apt-get install php-bcmath` and this install **php7.2-bcmath**

Comment: Have you tried a `apt cache search php7.1`? It might be spelled a little different.

Comment: @TobiasF. I have `php7.1-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP` listed when I do `apt-cache search php7.1`

Comment: @apokryfos Already tried what is proposed on others questions but none of them are working and all are for Ubuntu, not Debian.

Comment: Hello man, i had a similar problem because i had wrong repo when i installed PHP 7.3 and i wasn't able to find some modules. Maybe this relates to your issue too. I hope it helps.

Comment: Try using the `packages.sury.org/php` repository intead of the `ppa:ondrej/php` one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) I was able to make it work by following instructions here : https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

```
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
apt-get update
```